# PHP directory location

Tags: php, path, location, directory

I can't understand how to save directory location.

The script is located in some subfolder of root one. Here is the example tree:

```
|-index.php
|-another.php
|+empty_folder
|+subfolder
|---script.php
```

I'm running from `script.php`. I have to save in database path for the `empty_folder`. In script I use the code:

```
if (is_writable($PATH)) ...
```

And it returns error every time (can't open the folder). Now `$PATH` looks like `../empty_folder` and this doesn't work.

Any ways?

Comment: What is the current working directory for script.php? `echo getcwd();`

Comment: @sitesafenl `/srv/http/wordpress/wp-admin` and I need the `wordpress` folder access. `empty_folder` is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ../ try the use of the full path: `if(is_writeable('/srv/http/wordpress/'))`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I got the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and built the path.

Answer (score 1):

is_writable only returns false if the specified path cannot be written to by the current user ID. That can be because the path doesn't exist, or the current user ID doesn't have the writes to write there.

What are the permissions on empty_folder (user/group + permissions) and what userID/groupID is your script running under (web server's?).